# How do I call a method from another method of the same NSObject?

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

I have two methods in my NSObject.

I would like to know how to set the text in one method from another, and then execute that method from the one where I set the text?

This is what I have done so far.. just getting abit lost trying to pass things between views and setting up tableviews.

```
- (IBAction) getManufacturers
{
    //set manufacture.php
    NSString *manufactureString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"manufacture.php"];
    submissionString = manufactureString;
    self.grabURLInBackground; //<--- this is wrong, how do I call my other method?
}

//...


- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/CodeTest/%@", settexthere];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

//UPdated:
So what I ended up doing is just adding a NSString paramater to grabURLInBackground method which is set from my other method like describeded below

```
[self grabURLInBackground:submissionString];
```

all is well.

Now I just need to figure out how to pass the data I have coming in to a new uitableview.. :)
thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Your manufactureString is leaking and should be released. Or better yet, just do submissionString = @manufacture.php". And since submissionString is probably a retained property, use this self.submissionString = @manufacture.php" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self grabURLInBackground:nil];
```

this should work if you declared the function in the prototype

I think you want to set the string? In this case you need a new function

**prototype**

`- (void) grabURLInBackgroundWithSubmission:(NSString*):submission;`

**implementation**

```
- (void) grabURLInBackgroundWithSubmission:(NSString*):submission{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/instaCodeTest/%@", submission];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

and call it with
`[self grabURLInBackgroundWithSubmission:submissionString];`

Comment: what will happen if I set the id to a string, as that function is from the ASIHttpRequest warpper.. I was thinking of changing but I wasnt sure if it would mess up the function.

Comment: actually dont answer that.. Im just going to make my own method with NSStrin *... thanks for the answer.

Comment: gets the function called from somewhere else, like in Interfacebuilder? If not you can overwrite it

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
[self grabURLInBackground:nil]
```

But you may want to move the functionality from grabURLInBackground to another method so that you won't have to pass a dummy nil parameter.